# ASP.NET Reload (Redirect) view without changing the back button order for chrome

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-5

Can I somehow redirect or reload the page without an entry in the back button queue (or history.back() in JS)?

Currently, I'm using "RedirectToAction()" as the return value for a Post to save data.

```
    public virtual ActionResult NotizAktualisieren(long id, string notiz)
    {
        var data = Client.Get<TestlaufAusfuehrung>(id);

        data.Notiz = notiz;

        Client.Put(data);

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Ergebnisse), new { id });
    }
```

Firefox seems to automatically ignore same entries, what can I do for chrome?